# How to correctly stop a thread that is waiting for input from stdIn?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've implemented a simple chat application that receives messages and redirects them to all users because I'm learning about parallel programming.

The client has two threads: One for listening the server and other (the main thread) to write to the server.

These are the codes used to implement this:

Main Thread:

```
    try {
        Thread listener = new Thread(new Receiver(in));
        listener.start();
        while (listener.isAlive()) {
            out.println(stdIn.readLine());
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error trying to send text to server" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Runnable for second thread:

```
public class Receiver implements Runnable {

    private BufferedReader in;

    public Receiver(BufferedReader serverInput) {
        this.in = serverInput;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String responseLine;
        try {
            while ((responseLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(responseLine);

                if (responseLine.contains("Bye")) break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Erro ao receber mensagem do servidor: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The client is supposed to send a message (#quit) in order to quit the chat to which the server will respond with a message (Bye) that will finish the client app.

**How do I stop the main thread after the receiver thread has stopped it's life cicle?**

I used the `isAlive()` method to finish it, but after the user sends the #quit message the thread is still alive and it falls again on `stdIn.readline()` which interrupts the thread until the user sends another message even though he's already disconnected.

I tried implementing another thread (called sender) to send messages to the server and using `listener.join()` on the main thread to interrupt the sender thread with `Thread.interrupt()`, but the sender thread still falls on the `stdIn.readline()` method and i don't know how to properly interrupt the IO.

if anyone wants to read the full code, it's available in this [github page](https://github.com/edujtm/java-fundamentals/tree/master/lesson5/simple-chat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void run() {
    String responseLine;
    try {
        while(!isInterrupted()) 
        while ((responseLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(responseLine);

            if (responseLine.contains("Bye")) break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Erro ao receber mensagem do servidor: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**From another thread, call `interrupt()` on the thread in order to shut it down**

for example, before you print the stdInput check if it's "bye" then call interrupt

---

you can also use a flag like `isRunning` and call a method `shutdown()`

```
//member variable 
 private static volatile boolean isRunning = true;

public static void shutdown()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while( running )
        {
            //do whatever.
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried calling the `interrupt()` method from another thread, but the main thread still waits for input on `readline()` even after the call to interrupt. Basically what's happening is that the user still need to send a last useless message before quitting. 

The flag solution worked with the help of `Thread.sleep()` that sleeps until the server responds, throwing an exception if the thread is interrupted. But I imagine this is prone to errors.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy solution to this since reading from streams is a blocking operation, one trick I saw implemented in EHCache/Terracotta is using 2 threads instead of 1, one thread will do the actual reading from the stream(Callable),while another thread will setup an executor service and submit the first thread(task) (using [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html][1])).

This [article](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue153.html) has a detailed description .